# Soma de 2 colunas do data.frame

Tags: r, soma

Preciso somar duas colunas de um data.frame.

Exemplo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Preiso somar todas as linhas das colunas rural e urbano.

Tentei os códigos apply e rowsum e todos deram erro.

Erro apply:
apply(educa[, 3:4], 2, sum)
Error in FUN(newX[, i], ...) : 'type' inválido (character) do argumento

> 

Erro rowsum:
rowSums(educa[,3:4])
Error in rowSums(educa[, 3:4]) : 'x' deve ser numérico

> educ["Matrículas Estaduais"] = rowSums(educa[,3:4])

Comment: Bem-vinda ao StackOverflow em Português! Infelizmente, esta pergunta não pode ser reproduzida por quem for tentar respondê-la. Por favor, dê uma olhada [neste link](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/6700/como-fazer-uma-pergunta-reproduz%C3%ADvel-em-r/6701#6701) (principalmente no uso da função `dput`) e veja como fazer uma pergunta reproduzível em R. Assim, as pessoas que desejarem te ajudar conseguirão fazer isto da melhor maneira possível.

Answer (score 0):

Tem de converter para numérico antes de somar.

Mas primeiro veja com `str(educa[3:4])` a classe das colunas:
Se as colunas de `educa[3:4]` forem de classe `"factor"`

```
educa[3:4] <- lapply(educa[3:4], function(x) as.numeric(as.character(x)))
```

Se as colunas de `educa[3:4]` forem de classe `"character"`

```
educa[3:4] <- lapply(educa[3:4], as.numeric)
```

Depois é só somar as colunas.

```
rowSums(educa[3:4])
```